# Help with choosing a good font combo for a business survey

Tags: fonts, typekit

Could anyone suggest a good font or combination of fonts that I can use for my online business survey?  I have access to typekit, so would be great if the font choice was available from them.

I'm looking for safe bet as it's a business survey, any combo that looks professional and is easy to read would be great.

I know very little about fonts so please if I can provide any more information let me know.

Comment: Please explain the reason for voting down the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with a classic Helvetica/Garamond blend - it's a proven classic.
For a quick look at combos that work, I typically use http://bonfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/19-top-fonts-in-19-top-combinations-chart.pdf

If you are looking to build your unique combination I can recommend reading:

- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/04/best-practices-of-combining-typefaces/
- http://www.surl.org/usabilitynews/81/personalityoffonts.asp

Comment: Thanks Bogdan, good links and thanks for the advice on the Helvetica/Garamon blend.  Typekit have Nimbus Sans so will try that with the Garamond.

Answer (score 0):

Good answer above, I can also recommend Typewolf.com, which suggests complementary font combos and shows examples of them in action.